# How to get all Div within a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html-table

Please tell me how can I get array of all Those DIV of specific table whose LANG="1" using 
Javascript

Table structure is like this:

```
  < table >
 < tr > < td > < div id=1 lang="1" > some metter < /div > < /td >< /tr >
 < tr > < td > < div id=2 lang="2" > some metter < /div > < /td >< /tr >
 < tr > < td > < div id=3 lang="1" > some metter < /div > < /td >< /tr >
 < tr > < td > < div id=4 lang="1" > some metter < /div > < /td >< /tr >
< /table >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could give the `table` a unique id and then use the `getElementsByTagName` function:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableId');
if (table == null) return;
var divs = table.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var div = divs[i];
    if (div.lang == '1') {
        alert(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear... all most everybuddy has given correct answer but i felt ur answer really very simple and very good...

Answer (score 3):

what happend with ol' plain javascript?

> var divs =
>   document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('div');

**edit** : forgot last part

```
var divLang = []; 
for(a in divs){
  ((divs[a].getAttribute('lang')) ==1)? divLang.push(divs[a]) : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest if you use a library like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), etc., which offer a nearly-full set of [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/).

Using Prototype, it would look like this:

```
var table = /* ...an expression finding the table...*/;
var divs = table.select('div[lang=1]');
```

So for instance, if you give your table an `id` of "myTable":

```
var table = $('myTable');
var divs = table.select('div[lang=1]');
```

Or just

```
var divs = $('myTable').select('div[lang=1]');
```

Using jQuery, if you give that `id` to your table, it's:

```
var divs = $('#myTable div[lang=1]');
```

(Yes, jQuery and Prototype both use `$`, but for different things.)

Comment: giving me error: table.select is not a function (here table is var table "

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('table[lang="1"]');
```

or assign them class lets say "divclass" and select them

```
$('.divclass[lang="1"]');
```

This is jQuery syntax since someone else posted in prototype

Comment: That gives him *all* divs in *all* tables, and doesn't filter by `lang` as requested.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Sorry I didn't see that requirement here I'll update my answer